# How to make a sliding-text effect (text entering gradually)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations, elementor

I want to make a title that enters letter-by-letter, similar to the animation of [**Sliding Text** from the *Elements* Wordpress Theme](https://essentials.pixfort.com/original/sliding-text/) and [as animated on this web-page](https://localmedia.ch/).

#### Issues

But I don't know how to make the effect work when the screen arrives at the element as an entrance animation.

I'm using [*Elementor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementor) in Wordpress, but I haven't found ways to do it.

My current code is also on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tomasag/pen/oNYPvop):

#### HTML

```
<h1>
  <div class="slide-in-container">
    <span class="slide-in">Lorem ipsum dolor</span>
    </div><br> 
  <div class="slide-in-container">
    <span class="slide-in2">sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
   </div>
</h1>
```

#### CSS

```
.slide-in, .slide-in2{
  animation: slide-in-animation 1s forwards;
  opacity:0;
}

.slide-in2{
  animation-delay:.5s;
}

@keyframes slide-in-animation {
  from {opacity:0;
  line-height:4em;}
  to {opacity:1;
  line-height:1em;}
}

.slide-in-container{
  overflow-y:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  line-height:1.3em!important;
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to make that work is the Intersection Observer API ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)).

It allows you to place multiple intersection observers across sections. And if a section becomes visible to the user, you are notified. After that, you can add an activation class that starts the transition.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Keimeno, you could use intersection observers.
.slide-in and .slide-in2 will be added to the span, then it's atleast 50px above the bottom

On a side node, div's should not be placed in h1 tags (or h2-h6). I have added a style to the .slide-in-container class to handle this issue.

```js
/**
 * Adds a class to a child element
 * @param {Element} obj Target element
 */
function preloadSlideIn(obj) {
    let child = obj.querySelectorAll('span')[0];
    if (child) {
        if (obj.classList.contains('slide-in-container-first'))
            child.classList.add('slide-in');
        else if (obj.classList.contains('slide-in-container-second'))
            child.classList.add('slide-in2');
    }
}

// Wait for the DOM to be fully loaded
(() => {
    const
        slideIns = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-in-container'),
        slideInOptions = {
            threshold: 0,
            rootMargin: "0px 0px -50px 0px"
        };

    try {
        const slideInObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, slideInObserver) => {
            entries.forEach(o => {
                if (!o.isIntersecting) return;

                preloadSlideIn(o.target);
                slideInObserver.unobserve(o.target);
            });
        }, slideInOptions);

        slideIns.forEach(o => { slideInObserver.observe(o); });
    } catch (e) {
        // IntersectionObserver is not available for iOS < 12.0
        slideIns.forEach(o => {
            preloadSlideIn(o);
        });
    }
})();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 800px 0;
}
.slide-in,
.slide-in2 {
  animation: slide-in-animation 1s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
.slide-in2 {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@keyframes slide-in-animation {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    line-height: 4em;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    line-height: 1em;
  }
}
.slide-in-container {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 1.3em !important;
}
.slide-in-container span {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<hr />
<div>
    <div class="slide-in-container slide-in-container-first">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-in-container slide-in-container-second">
        <span>sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
```

Source: https://w3c.github.io/IntersectionObserver/